# Windows Mobile takes a long time to open a SQL Server CE database if it's created on a 64 bit OS

Tags: ado.net, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, 32bit-64bit

I have a Windows Mobile application that uses SQL Server CE 3.5.  When a handheld requests a System Update, it receives an .SDF file that’s generated on a Windows Server.  This system has been running on a Win 2003 server for several years without any problems.

I’m migrating the server processes from the Win 2003 server to a Win 2008 R2 server and have run into a problem.  After receiving the .SDF file from the new 64 bit server, the handheld takes more than 20 seconds to open a connection to it.  Opening a connection to the .SDF built on the 32bit Win 2003 server is virtually instantaneous.  My experimenting has shown that the problem occurs whenever the .SDF is built on a 64bit machine but does not occur if the .SDF is built on a 32 bit machine.

By the way, only the first connection opening is slow.  Subsequent openings are instantaneous.  Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: See my blog post here, http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html

Comment: I agree to ErikEJ blog post

Answer (score 1):

The indexes in the database are different on a device and a PC (32- or 64-bit).  On first open, the device detects that the indexes are invalid for the current platform, so it must delete and recreate them.  This takes time.  The only "solution" is to reindex them on a device on your end, then deploy the database that came from the device and not the one from the server.